# Error: Expected ; at end of declaration list - Class not recognized as type

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties

Here is my viewcontroller.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h>
#import <ImageIO/ImageIO.h>
#import <CoreVideo/CoreVideo.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate,  CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *selectedImageView;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *vImage;
@property(nonatomic, retain) AVCaptureStillImageOutput﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿ *stillImageOutput;

- (IBAction)photoFromAlbum;
- (IBAction)photoFromCamera;
- (IBAction)saveImageToAlbum;
- (IBAction)segueToChoosePhotoTypeViewController;

@end
```

The line:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) AVCaptureStillImageOutput﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿ *stillImageOutput;
```

is generating the following issue:

```
Expected ; at end of declaration list.
```

Xcode isn't recognizing AVCaptureStillImageOutput as a class as it remains black and doesn't suggest it as a type, and the "Fix-it" wants to insert the `;` right after AVCaptureStillImageOutput.

However, if I try to use declare AVCaptureStillImageOutput as a type in viewDidLoad of my viewController.m file, it recognizes it and allows it as a type. Also, the rest of the AVFoundation classes are being recognized in the code there.

The framework is there, I'm just having an issue with this `@property` declaration.

Comment: That was a tricky one (see answer below)! (+1) for copy/pasting your actual code, otherwise it would have been impossible to solve this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your line

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) AVCaptureStillImageOutput *stillImageOutput;
```

you have some **invisible characters** between `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` and `*stillImageOutput`. If I paste this line into the vi editor, it looks like this:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) AVCaptureStillImageOutput<feff><feff><feff><feff><feff> *stillImageOutput;
```

(U+FEFF is a Unicode Byteorder marker, and it looks like a normal space in Xcode, even if "Show Invisibles" is activated).

Deleting and re-inserting the space fixes the problem.

Comment: Wow. You've saved me so much misery. I copied this line of code from a tutorial, and will be sure to remember this fix if something like this happens again.

Comment: It looks like a normal space in Xcode, even with Show Invisibles, because it **IS** a space. U+FEFF is a `ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE`. That means it is a space of zero width, such not displaying it at all by default is intended, correct default behavior of Xcode. If you show invisibles, Xcode displays every character as a character of some kind, ignoring the fact that it may be zero width, yet this space is still a space and thus displayed as one (unlike normal ASCII spaces, that are displayed by a special placeholder character in this mode).

Comment: @Mecki: That is exactly why it was a bit difficult to find the actual cause for the problem. The Xcode option "Show Invisibles" did not help.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the `Editor` menu, select `Show Invisibles`. Note that you have plenty of invisible, non printable characters between the `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` and the `*`. Delete everything between these two and finally put there a single space again. Those invisible characters, even though not printable, were taken as part of your class name. Once you are done, you can select `Hide Invisibles` again. Be careful when copy/pasting code, you even copy/pasted those "bad characters" into your SO question above.

Comment: Can you recognize the characters as illegal when you paste the OP's code into Xcode? I tried this, but this special character U+FEFF looks like a normal space in my Xcode, even when "Show Invisibles" is selected.

Comment: That's because U+FEFF **IS** a space character. The name of this character is `ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE`, so it is an Unicode "space" character of "zero width" (hence invisible by default) and an automatic line break may not be added directly before this character. Not displaying this character by default is correct behavior of Xcode, that's how it is supposed to be displayed. When you enable invisibles, the character is displayed, yet it is still a space and has no visible character shape.

Comment: That is also correct. U+FEFF is a BOM (see http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html), and "For backwards compatibility it should be treated as ZERO WIDTH NON-BREAKING SPACE". - I was just wondering why you said in your answer *"Note that you have plenty of invisible, non printable characters"*, because (as you said) this character is displayed as a space and is therefore not recognizable as invisible/non printable.

Comment: They were invisible, weren't they? And as they have a "zero width", they are non-printable (how do you print a character that has zero width?), so what was wrong about that statement? Show Invisibles in Xcode does not guarantee, that a replacement character is displayed for every existing Unicode character, but it does guarantee is that every character is displayed as "something" (a space is something, it's not nothing). So if you toggle this option and spaces start appearing somewhere, those must be invisible, non-printable characters (with no replacement character in Xcode).