# expected ';' at the end of declaration list

Tags: objective-c, expectations

```
error:- expected ';' at the end of the declaration list
```

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    float number;                   error:- expected ';' at the end of the declaration list
    float result;
    int currentoperation;
    __weak IBOutlet UILabel *label;
}

- (IBAction)canceloperation:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)cancelnumber:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)buttonoperation:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)buttonnumber:(id)sender;


@end
```

Please fix this code.

Comment: We don't "Please fix this code" here.  We expect a bit of effort out of you, try asking a question instead.

Comment: Have you tried searching?  How about [Error: Expected ; at end of declaration list - Class not recognized as type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365116/error-expected-at-end-of-declaration-list-class-not-recognized-as-type)?  Or any of the "Related" questions on the right >>

Comment: possible duplicate of [error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before...in Objective C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246509/error-expected-specifier-qualifier-list-before-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 25):

The OP's question is stated quite bad, but there is a genuine problem here.

The problem occurs when Xcode `C Language Dialect` is set to `C99` instead of `GNU99`. C99 does not have a declaration for `typeof()`, and will assume it returns `int`.
Then, the following bunch of confusing error messages are logged:

```
warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'
  __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
  ~~~~~~ ^
'__weak' only applies to Objective-C object or block pointer types; type here is 'int'
  __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
  ^
a parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition
  __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
                ^
expected ';' at end of declaration
  __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
                     ^
```

To change this: open the Project Navigator > click the project > click the target > Select the C Language Dialect > Hit backspace to set the default value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, Berik.  I'm working on a project that was initially started in 2009 and added a library that was having this problem. Your answer worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I had the same issue with C99 setting, Compiler Default works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks, worked with unity and there was such a problem.

Answer (score -3):

This is a duplicate of the many "invisible character" questions.   You have an invisible character in your code.

If you have a history of using emacs or using the ctrl key, you could easily have tapped ctrl-return and inserted an invisible character.

http://www.friday.com/bbum/2012/12/23/xcode-sometimes-a-return-is-not-a-return-emacs-brain-damage/