# Issue while integration GCM with iOS app using objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-messaging, cocoapods

I am getting errors while using GCM code from this link [Implementing GCM Client on iOS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client?configured=true)

Here is my code .

[image]

Referred the code from here:[Google appDelegate code](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/ios/gcm/GcmExample/AppDelegate.m)

Can anyone please tell me why I am getting this error?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: issue is in some compile objective C setting for create weakself checkout: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24491427/1280373

Comment: @ Nitin Gohel thanks a lot..Your reference fixed my issue