# declaring directory when using collection View

Tags: ios, directory, save, uicollectionview

I do not know how to declare your directory in the .h file.  In my View Controller I have written

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSArray *allImagesArray = [[NSArray alloc ]init];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *location=@"Hats";
    NSString *fPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:location];
    NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: fPath];
    for(NSString *str in directoryContent){
        NSString *finalFilePath = [fPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:finalFilePath];
        if(data)
        {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            [allImagesArray addObject:image];
}}}
```

however of course I get an error saying no visible at interface for"NSMutableArray" declares the selector  "addObject".I do not know how to declare my directory called Hats in the .h file.  I think you use NSMutableArray or something but I don't know for sure..

Answer (score 0):

You want to use an NSMutableArray instead of an NSArray. You can't alter an NSArray after creation.

Comment: ok then Can you tell me how to declare it in a NSMutabelArray since I am struggling with the declaration bit.  I think I do not need to change anything in implementation file rite?

Comment: All you would have to do in this case is change `NSArray *allImagesArray = [[NSArray alloc ]init];` to `NSMutableArray *allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]init];`

Comment: And what should I write for declaration?

Comment: `NSMutableArray *allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]init];`

Comment: However  I am getting an error saying expected"."at the end of the declaration list which is pointing at the = sign

Comment: The error is `Expected ';' at end of declarations list` is the error

Comment: Try deleting this line and typing it again by hand. I've seen other people get this error when there are strange invisible characters pasted on a line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365116/error-expected-at-end-of-declaration-list-class-not-recognized-as-type

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]init];
```

And then you can do

```
[allImagesArray addObject:image];
```

NSArray needs to be populated when it is initialized. So if you want to add some object to an array then you have to use an NSMutableArray.

Comment: OK and I get an error saying expected"."at the end of the declaration list which is pointing at the = sign

Comment: That usually happens when there's an issue with spaces (when you have copy pasted the code). Retype it making sure its properly spaced. Or go to the `Editor` menu, select `Show Invisibles`. It will show up those empty characters.

Comment: Even though I used show Invisible I do not see useless spacing.